# Issues with Node/NPM Autocompletion

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I might have tried a million ways so far but to list a few:

1. Installed/Uninstalled Node. The current version is now LTS v18.17.1. Version of npm is 9.6.7
2. Initially tried with homebrew but the older version/LTS was giving me trouble. Downloaded the package directly from the node website
3. Moving forward, I was hoping to setup autocompletion for mac terminal. macOS Ventura 13.4.1

   1. Followed steps here: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-completion
   2. The `npm completion >> ~/.zshrc` gave me an autocompletion script similar to https://gist.github.com/jamischarles/1669accda0f057df1769c6c0e932827f

      1. I added the above to my .zshrc

This still doesn't work.

Below from the npm completion didn't make a lot of sense:

You may of course also pipe the output of `npm completion` to a file such as `/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/npm` or `/etc/bash_completion.d/npm` if you have a system that will read that file for you.

- I still went to this location but the /npm is not available in the path /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/

Any help and guidance would be highly appreciated.